# How to get the line number and highlighted text from iframe using jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, wysiwyg

I have text area in my page. For need of Text editor using WYSIWYG text editor. So I cannot get the line number and highlighted text.

Demo on jsfiddle: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fz9ctps3/12/)

**Javascript code**

```
var wysihtml5ParserRules = {
 tags: {
  strong: {},
  b:      {},
  i:      {},
  em:     {},
  br:     {},
  p:      {},
  div:    {},
  span:   {},
  ul:     {},
  ol:     {},
  li:     {},
  a:
  {
   set_attributes:
   {
     target: "_blank",
     rel:    "nofollow"
   },
   check_attributes:
   {
     href:   "url" // important to avoid XSS
   }
  }
 }
};
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("textarea",
{
  toolbar:        "toolbar",
  parserRules:    wysihtml5ParserRules,
  useLineBreaks:  true
});
var doc = document.getElementById("textarea");
var  mark = document.getElementById("mark");

function lineNum()
{
   return doc.value.substr(0, doc.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
}

function markAt(line)
{
  var mp = (line * 12)-2-doc.scrollTop;
  mark.style.top = String(mp)+"px";
  if (mp>4 && mp<200)
  {
    mark.style.display = "initial";
  } else {
    mark.style.display = "none";
  }
}

moveMark = setInterval(function(){markAt(lineNum());}, 100);
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form>
    <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
      <a data-wysihtml5-command="bold" title="CTRL+B">bold</a> |
      <a data-wysihtml5-command="italic" title="CTRL+I">italic</a>
     <a data-wysihtml5-action="change_view">Change Text Area</a>
    </div>
    <textarea id="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
    <img id="mark" src="data:image.png;"></img>  
    <br><input type="reset" value="Reset form!">
 </form>
```

In that fiddle click "Change Text Area". Every thing is working fine. 
But the textformating styles *bold* and *italic* is not working, if bold and italic working line number is not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is the connection to an iframe?

Comment: Iframe is generated runtime.. Please check Fiddle

Comment: It Generated by wysihtml5-0.4.0pre.min.js